# variable outside of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

can someone explain me why this happend ?

```
var Danny = {
    name: 'Danny',
    lastname: 'Black',
    yearOfBirth: 1998,
    job: 'Programmer',
    isMarried: false,
};

var xyz = 'job';
console.log(Danny[xyz]);
```

In this case I got Prgrammer in console why?

Comment: because `xyz` is a variable with value `job` and `Danny` is an object having a property `job`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: This isn't a question you ask on Stack Overflow. Check out some basic tutorials and your question will be answered. It's like you post a question on Math SE asking why 1+1=2. Grab a book (or video), learn the basics and when you have a problem you need help with, seek the community's help. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this `console.log(Danny["xyz"]);` then it will return `undefined` because there is no property with xyz in above object

If you use this `console.log(Danny[xyz]);` then it will replace `xyz` to `"job"` which means

`console.log(Danny["job"]);` that is why it is giving you `"Programmer"` as output.

Comment: When I use "." insteadof [] it returned undefined too

Comment: @Danny See [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/4642212).